# fscanf of double, int, and char within the textfile

Tags: c, char, int, double, scanf

Hi I am new to c programming and I am having troubles with scanning the int,double,and chars with in the text file I am using fscanf to scan the text file also here is the inside of the textfile.

-2

3.2

2e

e4

What I want is to display the data one by one Here is what my fscanf code:

```
double num;
char c;
while(val = fscanf(stdin,"%lf%c",&num,&c)){
if(val == 0){
\\wrong inputs}
else if(c = '\n'){
\\has chars}
else {
\\double
}
}
```

the problem is that the output will be -2.0,3.2
I dont want it to be -2.0 I want it to be just -2 plain is there a good and effecient way to do it?>

Comment: And how do you print them is important. Also why your question is titled reading from a file, when reading from stdin. Actually you are reading from a file, but bet that's not what you meant.

Comment: what I did is .2f, num   but when I tried to if ((num% 1)==0)) it always says can't use % it has (int , double)

Comment: because modulo is strictly for integer operands.

Comment: @zubergu sorry it was reading from stdin

Comment: and num%1 is always 0. Don't know what you tried do accomplish here, but obviously something wrong. Re-think what you're trying to do, edit your question according to that, and then, maybe you'll find somebody willing to help you.

Comment: To avoid trailing zeros in displaying a double, you can use `%g` format specifier: `printf("%lg\n", num);`